# TabLayout don't show tabs

Tags: android, android-support-design

my TabLayout don't work when I `setVisible(GONE)`, attach any fragment to Activity. Next I `setVisibility(VISIBLE)` and attach other fragment where is ViewPager. And `tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(this.viewPager);`

Second time it works.

TabLayout is in MainActivity.

Any idea?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? ViewPager doesn't populate any Fragment?

Answer (score 2):

I faced this similar problem and after searching, fell upon to this link
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=180462.
One of the solution is to call "setupWithViewPager" method in runnable posted to tabLayout. Code excerpt is as below:

```
final TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.plan_type_tabs);
ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
tabLayout.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(pager);
    }
});
```

This is working for me. Hopefully, this would work for you.